# Print an output file in a Format

Tags: shell, unix

I have an input file and I want to print it in a precise format in an output file:

Input file:

```
973260339343
973456375066
812456375066
```

Output file:

```
0 PIN_FLD_RESULTS       ARRAY [1]
1 PIN_FLD_POID   POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /bill 973260339343
0 PIN_FLD_RESULTS       ARRAY [2]
1 PIN_FLD_POID   POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /bill 973456375066
0 PIN_FLD_RESULTS       ARRAY [3]
1 PIN_FLD_POID   POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /bill 812456375066
```

I tried reading the file line by line, but I am not sure how to print it in the desired format.

Comment: When you include your attempt to read the file line by line, we can explain what went wrong there. `awk` would be a better solution, but you can benefit from the reaction on your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk):

```
awk '{printf "0 PIN_FLD_RESULTS       ARRAY [" NR "]\n1 PIN_FLD_POID   POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /bill %s\n", $1}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer following the guidelines, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and e.g. adjust the typesetting, add few explanations.